# Australian visa issue

Tags: bangladeshi-citizens

I applied for 309/100 on 16 /6/2017. due to my agents unprofessional dealing visa refused on 24 april/2018 and we applied to AAT. April 2 2019 my case remitted to home affairs. July 11/2019 they asjked for courst custody of my daughter and police verification once again and mean while sent my medical to get done. court custody took me time and on their approval of further time i submitted every single request on 28 August/2019. after that on my enquiery (after 2 months) they let me know they will finalise my case shortly and that was on 15 october/2019. Till today i have no news of finalisation or granting visa.My validity of health will be over 1 May/2020. They are not responding any of my mail. Total time since I have applied is 29 months now. what is actually happening? When can I expect my case be finalised and what infact shortly refers? Advice what should I do

Comment: The complexity of the application how many places are available in the migration program will affect processing timescales. It looks like the current timeframe is 20 months for 309 and 33 months for 100 https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/partner-offshore

Comment: thank you so much for the reply, but i have no clear concept on these. what do you mean by complexity of the application how many places are available in the migration program will affect processing timescales. what should i take by shortly they will finalise my case that they informed me.